# JAX-WS Deployment

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

Assuming that you build a web service using JAX-WS - how do you actually deploy this compared to a traditional web service / war file?

Assuming i have followed this guide http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/web-service/1145-how-create-java-web-service.html and have the following two classes;

```
package com.mycompany.service; 
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class HelloWeb {

    @WebMethod
    public String sayGreeting(String name) {
        return "Greeting " + name + "!";
    }
}


package com.mycompany.service; 
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9898/HelloWeb", new HelloWeb());
        System.out.println("HelloWeb service is ready");
    }
}
```

do i need to just export the project as a war in eclipse and then deploy that to tomcat?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you try that?

Comment: im not sure - is it the correct thing to try? I could try many things but by posting here I'm trying to determine what i should actually be doing?

Comment: when i try to export as a war file i get an error saying invalid module name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **wsgen** to generate Web service artifacts and then package those files in a WAR file and deploy to Tomcat (or any other JAX-WS enabled J2EE container eg. JBoss). 
You dont need to use **Endpoint.publish**. Tomcat will deploy and publish the Web service.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html

**javax.xml.ws.Endpoint** is an helper class to host a lightweight Web service in a J2SE environment without using JAX-WS enabled Web container. But this usage is not suitable for production.

Comment: how do you package it as a war file - I've managed to generate the wsgen files - but as the project is a normal java se application i am unable to export as war

Comment: Put all generated class files in WEB-INF\classes and your jar files in WEB_INF\lib.